# How can I redirect non-www to www.domain.com and along with that also keep the m.domain.com / subdomain.domain.com same as it is in nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I used this:

server {

     server_name "~^(?!www.).*" ;
     return 301 $scheme://www.$host$request_uri;
}

but this redirects everything. I need to write exceptions for subdomains along with this.

Comment: if you have a server block with an exact match for each of the subdomains, that should take priority over this regex block

Answer (score 0):

If the server block containing `server_name "~^(?!www.).*"` is matching `m.domain.com`, you obviously do not have another server block with a `server_name m.domain.com`.

Rather than use complex regular expressions to redirect website names to a default server block, you could use the default server block to perform the redirect instead.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 http://www.domain.com/$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com m.domain.com subdomain.domain.com;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more details.